# Strange behavior of php array and foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following code:

```
$array = array(
    array("name"=>"John"),
    array("name"=>"Rob"),
    array("name"=>"Tom"),
);
foreach($array as &$el)
    $el["age"]=23;

foreach($array as $el)
    echo $el["name"] . " is: " . $el["age"] . " years old<br>";
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```
John is: 23 years old
Rob is: 23 years old
Tom is: 23 years old
```

but I actually receive the following:

```
John is: 23 years old
Rob is: 23 years old
Rob is: 23 years old
```

Why is that ? In the first foreach loop I'm using reference to edit the source array.

Comment: just unset `unset($el);`

Comment: @Sean, Yes, same problem here. @ArturoO, You need to just add `unset($el);` after first loop

Comment: Thank for the info !